# can't login to phpmyadmin with laravel docker-compose

Tags: laravel-5, phpmyadmin, docker-compose

this is my docker-compose.yml:

## https://github.com/hitalos/laravel

```
web:
    image: hitalos/laravel:latest
    ports:
        - 82:80
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
    links:
        - db
    environment:
        DB_HOST: db
        DB_DATABASE: dbname
        DB_USERNAME: root
        DB_PASSWORD: example
        DB_CONNECTION: mysql
        COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT: 1000
db:
    image: mysql
    ports: 
        - 3306:3306    
    environment:
        # with mysql
        MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: example
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
        - ../data:/var/lib/mysql

        # with postgres
        #POSTGRES_DB: dbname
        #POSTGRES_USER: username
        #POSTGRES_PASSWORD: p455w0rd
phpmyadmin:
  image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
  links:
    - db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8181:80
  environment:
    MYSQL_USERNAME: user
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123789
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

I can't login to phpmyadmin with error:
Cannot log in to the MySQL server
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [official phpmyadmin](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/) docker image, which is `phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin`. It is very well documented and what you would need is something like:

```
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  links:
    - db
  ports:
    - 8181:80
  environment:
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    - PMA_USER=user
    - PMA_PASSWORD=123789
    - PMA_HOST=db
    - PMA_PORT=3306
```

Comment: Create database 
No Privileges

Comment: Is this an error message you are getting? If yes: From which container is this output?

Comment: phpmyadmin. when I try to login to phpmyadmin from web.

Comment: Thanks, this solves a problem where I could not access to PhpMyAdmin, because no login form was displayed. By adding those environment values I could have access to the DB.